# how to extract value from php and pass to jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to calculate the distance between two airports and return this value to jquery function and use this value in furthur calculation. 
i don't know where's wrong?

html: the dept and dest inputs retrieved airport information from database

```
  <form id="airform1" class="on">
    <div>
        From
        <div class="textinput">
            <input type="text" id="dept" name="departure" placeholder="City name or aiport code" >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        To
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="dest" placeholder="City name or airport code" >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        Via
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="via" placeholder="City name or airport code" >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="trip" value="2.0">Round-trip <br>
            <input type="radio" name="trip" value="1.0">One-way
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        Number of flights/passengers
        <input type="text" id="numpass" value="1">
    </div>

    <div>
        Class
        <select style="width: 82px">
            <option selected="selected" value="1.0">Economy</option>
            <option value="2.04">Business</option>
            <option value="2.69">First</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="line">

    </div>
    </form>
```

php code:

```
    <?php


    if(isset($_POST['dept'], $_POST['dest'])){
    $dept=$_POST['dept'];
    $dest=$_POST['dest'];
   }



        mysql_connect("localhost","abv","asdasda") or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("asda") or die(mysql_error());


       $strSQL1 = "SELECT display, lat, longi FROM airport WHERE display = '$dept'";
       $rs1 = mysql_query($strSQL1);
       $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($rs1);
       $lat1= $row1['lat'];
       $long1= $row['longi'];

       $strSQL2 = "SELECT display, lat, longi FROM airport WHERE display = '$dest'";
       $rs2 = mysql_query($strSQL2);
       $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
       $lat2= $row1['lat'];
       $long2= $row['longi'];



$earthradius = 6366.707;    
    $km_to_miles = 1/1.609344;

    $radlat1 = M_PI * (lat1)/180;
    $radlat2 = M_PI * (lat2)/180;

    $radlng1 = M_PI * (long1)/180;
    $radlng2 = M_PI * (long2)/180;

    $radlng1 += M_PI / 2;
    $radlng2 += M_PI / 2;

    if($radlng1<0)
        radlng1 += M_PI * 2;
    if($radlng2<0)
        radlng2 += M_PI * 2;

    $x1 = $earthradius * cos($radlng1) * sin($radlat1);
    $y1 = $earthradius * sin($radlng1) * sin($radlat1);
    $z1 = $earthradius * cos($radlat1);

    $x2 = $earthradius * cos($radlng2) * sin($radlat2);
    $y2 = $earthradius * sin($radlng2) * sin($radlat2);
    $z2 = $earthradius * cos($radlat2);

    $d = sqrt(($x1-$x2)*($x1-$x2)+($y1-$y2)*($y1-$y2)+($z1-$z2)*($z1-$z2));

    $theta = acos(($earthradius*$earthradius + $earthradius * $earthradius - $d * $d)/(2 * $earthradius * $earthradius));

    $distance = $theta * $earthradius;
    $miles = $distance * $km_to_miles;

    $co2 = (($miles / 41.986) * 20.88 * 2.7) / 2204.6;

    echo $co2; 

 ?>
```

javascript:  there's nothing showing up at the airanswer  i did not figure out where went wrong?

```
     $("#dept").change(function(){
            $("#dest").change(function(){
                var dept = $("#dept").val();
                var dest = $("#dest").val();
                $.post('airtravel.php',{dept: dept, dest: dest}, function(data){
                    $("#aircalc").click(function(){
                        $("#airanswer").html(data);
                    });

                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: I'm unclear on your question - does you code work?  Do you get a result?

Comment: Are you starting variables in javascript with $?

Comment: @Sbls: That's a common thing to do with jQuery objects.  It can help you remember what they are.

Comment: @SurrealDreams: Well, in this case it's simply an error. No initialisation of either dist or carbon. `var` missing. Declaration of `$carbon`, usage of `carbon`

Comment: neither `$dist` or `$carbon` are Jquery objects in this case. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that comes from your server side script is HTML; since you're using it in Ajax, it might be a better idea to return a JSON response:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('co2' => $co2));
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
$.post('airtravel.php',{dept: dept, dest:dest},function(data){
    var dist = data.co2,
    passengers = $("#numpass"),
    carbon = dist * passengers;

    $("#airanswer").text(carbon);
});
```

Comment: I added the above lines, but after clicking still nothing shows up ?

Comment: @user3371790 Could you put what you have tried in a pastebin and pass the link?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/en0nNfB3 this should be the link. Thank you for helping out :)

Comment: @user3371790 Updated my answer, you shouldn't try to assign a new click handler inside the callback.